# iText 7 itextpdf.kernel.PdfException

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm using java and iText 7 to generate PDF.

I created a PDF template and has some data models inside this template in order to make it dynamic.

When first time I used this template to generate PDF, it worked fine. But second time I tried to modify the data value inside the template then generate again it raised an error.

```
2016-09-24 18:35:17,589|http-bio-8080-exec-20|INFO|CustomerControllercom.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: pdf.inderect.object.belong.to.other.pdf.document.Copy.object.to.current.pdf.document
com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: pdf.inderect.object.belong.to.other.pdf.document.Copy.object.to.current.pdf.document
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:184)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:174)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:104)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:176)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:104)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:176)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:104)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter.writeToBody(PdfWriter.java:315)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter.flushObject(PdfWriter.java:232)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.flushObject(PdfDocument.java:1257)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.flush(PdfObject.java:147)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.flush(PdfObject.java:124)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObjectWrapper.flush(PdfObjectWrapper.java:97)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.flush(PdfPage.java:410)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.flush(PdfPage.java:367)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:720)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.close(Document.java:115)
```

Comment: The iText 7 Version I'm using : 7.0.0

Comment: Most likely your code using itext is incorrect.

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I isolated the code caused the error, commented out all usage of PdfFont, it worked fine.

I checked a Chinese blog, seems like this error is cause by didn't release some document objects(like PdfFont in my case) when you want to print this PDF again.
http://blog.csdn.net/fu250/article/details/52604900

I would much appreciate if someone can give a more detailed answer.

> public final PdfFont regular;
>      public final PdfFont bold;
>
> public InvoiceRecieptServiceImpl() throws IOException {
>          this.regular = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA);
>          this.bold = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA_BOLD);
>      }

Comment: You have not yet shown your code. I don't understand Chinese, and the Google translation is not helpful. Do you probably use the identical `PdfFont` instances for different target documents. I would advice against that.